# Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be two sequences with all positive terms. Does $|\frac{a_n}{b_n} - 1| < \epsilon$ imply that $|a_n - b_n| < \epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be two sequences with all positive terms. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Let $N$ be a positive integer such that $|\frac{a_n}{b_n} - 1| < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. Does it imply that $|a_n - b_n| < \epsilon$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too obvious?

Choose $\epsilon <1.$

$a_n=n+1$; $b_n=n.$

Comment: Is there a proof for the general case？

Comment: sihan Chen. General case? There are sequences for which it is true:  Choose $b_n:=a_n$; the above is a counterexample.

Comment: If $a_n$ and $b_n$ are the partial sums of the same sequence, let's say $s_a$ and $s_b$ with $a<b$(a,b are positive integer), will it make a difference?

Comment: Mr. Chen. Let $a_n, b_n$ converge to $1$. Then your two conditions are satisfied. Example: $a_n=1+1/n$; $b_n=1-1/n$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left|\frac{a_n}{b_n}-1\right|=|b_n|^{-1}|a_n-b_n|\lt\epsilon\\$$
$$\therefore|b_n|\le1\implies|a_n-b_n|\lt|b_n|\epsilon\le\epsilon\\$$

Comment: Why do we have $|b_n| \leq 1$?

Comment: Because else $|b_n|\epsilon > \epsilon $ and the last step is invalid.